# support all browsers except internet explorer

Tags: html

This is a simple code to display search on textbox. but it does not works on internet explorer. why?

```
<div id="rightsearch_div1">
   <input id="text_box" placeholder="search..." type="text"  />
</div>
```

Comment: The `placeholder` attribute was not implemented until IE 10.

Comment: -1. Please dont write this kind of question. I tested on Netscape Navigator a suprising dont work too. :) First read documentation, second try Google and then use SO!!!

Answer (score 2):

It works in IE10.

Things don't work in browsers that didn't implement it when they were released.

Answer (score 1):

It should work in the latest IE. I like using this site to check cross-browser compatibility on these things:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder